# Python pandas when sorting table, choose ascending/decending based on value of a column?

Tags: python, pandas, function, numpy, sorting

I have a df with these columns: time, username, aisle_id, seat_id.

I want to sort the table by:

1st: time, ascending,

2nd: username ascending,

3rd: aisle_id ascending,

4th: seat_id, ascending when aisle_id is odd number, and descending when aisle_id is even.

I tried to separate df into df_odd and df_even, sort both according to 4th rule using df.sort_values, then concat, then sort by 1st, 2nd and 3rd rule. However this breaks the 4th rule.

Is there a function for doing this, or was I trying the right way at first?

Answer (score 2):

You can groupby by time, username and aisle_id, and then sort values by seat_id within each group based on the values of aisle_id.

To sort within groups, create function func():

```
def func(x):
    if (x["aisle_id"].iloc[0]%2 == 0):
        ans = x["seat_id"].sort_values(ascending=False)
    else:
        ans = x["seat_id"].sort_values()
    return ans
```

Then groupby and apply func():

```
ans = 
df.groupby(["time","username","aisle_id"]).apply(func).reset_index(level=[0,1,2])
```

Since groupby automatically sorts the groups in ascending order, there is no need to sort by time, username, and aisle.

As an example, for the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["time","username","aisle_id","seat_id"])
df.loc[:,"time"] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
df.loc[:,"username"] = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
df.loc[:,"aisle_id"] = [1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2]
df.loc[:,"seat_id"] = [0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
print(df)

   time username aisle_id  seat_id
0    0     0        1       0
1    0     0        1       1
2    0     1        3       3
3    0     1        3       1
4    1     2        2       1
5    1     2        2       2
6    1     3        2       3
7    1     3        2       4
```

the output ans is

```
    time username aisle_id  seat_id
0    0      0       1        0
1    0      0       1        1
3    0      1       3        1
2    0      1       3        3
5    1      2       2        2
4    1      2       2        1
7    1      3       2        4
6    1      3       2        3
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a smart answer!